# How to make a Tensor that has the number of times its indexes are in another Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing, counting

Say I have a Tensor `I` of shape (batch_size x N) where values are integers `< max_indexes`.

I want, **without using any loop**, to create a Tensor `A` of shape (batch_size x max_indexes) where `A[batch_num,i]` is the number of times `i` appears in `I[batch_num]`.

For example (`batch_size=3, N=4, max_indexes=9`):

If I have

```
>>> I
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[2, 6, 5, 5],
       [1, 2, 0, 3],
       [4, 2, 1, 0]])>
```

I want

```
>>> A
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 9), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])>
```

Anyone has any idea to solve this?
I did this already using a for loop*, but it is a bit time-consuming...

*For loop implementation:

```
repeat_range = tf.transpose(tf.repeat([tf.range(max_indexes)],batch_size,0))
A = tf.zeros((batch_size,max_indexes))
for i in range(I.shape[1]):
    A += tf.transpose(tf.cast(repeat_range == I[:,i],tf.float32))
```

Comment: Can you show your for loop implementation?

Comment: Hi AloneTogether, just edited the post with the for loop implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! Need to use `tf.math.bincount`:

```
A = tf.math.bincount(I, axis=-1)
```

Note, if you need the second dimension of `A` being `max_indexes`, you can pad like this:

```
A = tf.math.bincount(a, axis=-1, minlength=max_indexes, maxlength=max_indexes)
```